# long question title is horrible

Tags: discussion

I just today came a cross couple of questions ([here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69163/all-steps-of-this-code-work-except-the-last-step-which-fails-to-evaluate-a-funct) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69131/how-can-i-create-the-following-3d-graphics-object-a-minimal-surface-with-trefoi)) with long long titles. It is really annoying and makes the SE page looks ugly.

Shouldn't be a rule for this?

Thanks

**Update**

The questions mentioned in the links have been edited and the titles are now shorter than before.

Comment: Titles should also start with a capital letter, unless they start with xkcd of course :).

Comment: （ ﾟДﾟ）[I didn't know!……](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1871/xzczd?tab=questions)

Answer (score 3):

I think with rare exception a title can be made significantly shorter than that without losing all meaning and uniqueness.  I encourage users to edit over-length titles when they encounter them.  If any details exist only in the title please move them to the question body.

Comment: On the other hand, don't make it [too short and unique](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64492/5) :P

Comment: @rm-rf LOL -- You are *still* welcome to rename that question!

Comment: Quite a few beginner questions have "Mathematica" in the title. IMHO that should always be removed, as in 99.99% of the cases it is utterly redundant on this site. "Problem with..." is a good second I'd say.