# "Doing XXX" vs "How to do XXX?" in question titles

Tags: discussion

Recently [my question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/147368/5208), initially titled "*How to avoid suppressing of messages by NIntegrate?*" was edited (in v3) to change the title to "*Avoiding the suppression of messages by NIntegrate*" by a high-rep user. As this site is literally `a question and answer site for users of Wolfram Mathematica` (the formulation visible for non-logged-in users on main page), I supposed that question titles should look like questions, and be formulated as such. But apparently it isn't, if the editor wasn't mistaken.

Is it really preferable to title the questions like "Doing XXX" instead of "How to do XXX?", even though the former formulation doesn't look like a *question*, while the latter summarizes the question body?

Comment: There are nearly 7000 questions with "how to" in the title, nearly 800 with "how do I", and 80 with "how do you"....Harder to search for the "*ing" type.  But your style of title seems to have plenty of company.  I would consider it a matter of taste that I would leave up to the OP.

Comment: Unlike some other SE sites, here the preference seems to be for a short title giving the topic, followed by a precise question in the body.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/1871

Comment: OTOH, "the suppression of messages" reads better than "suppressing of messages."  Perhaps the editor changed the "How to avoid" simultaneously, because it just happened to sound better at the time and not because there was anything wrong with it.

Comment: ^ agreed with @MichaelE2 - to a native English speaker at least, the revised title reads better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am the one who edited the title. My goal, as always, was to improve readability of the title by making the English more idiomatic. It occurs to me now that

> How can I keep NIntegrate from suppressing messages?

might have been a better edit, but ...

1. I didn't think of this wording at the time.
2. I liks titles to be concise. "How can I ... " is just decoration. It lengthens the title with adding any information about the problem.
3. The title is not the question. One should always state the full question in the body of the post.

My edits should not be considered definitive. OPs should feel free to roll them back or edit them further.